# How can I make a function wait until a previous line of code is complete

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some automated scripts in the browser. I have some steps that only work if I set a timeout:

```
function contactDetails(x) {
    document.querySelector("selector7").value=x;
    document.querySelector("selector8").dispatchEvent(new Event('change',{
        bubbles: true
    }));
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("selector9").click()
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("selector10").click()
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('selector11').click()
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('selector12').click()
    }, 6000);
        setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("selector13").click()
    }, 7000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("selector14").click()
    }, 7500);

};
```

I've been using timeouts to allow the previous step to complete. The lines set at 5000 are dependent on the lines above, and the lines set at 6000, 7000 and 7500 are dependent on everything else. Is there anything that I can use that would let the code in a line finish executing before the next line starts?

Comment: what happens if you do that without the timeout?

Comment: is the click on the selectors produce some kind of effect ?

Comment: Use function callback instead of set timeout. reference:- https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to promisify the `setTimeout`, then `await` it whenever you want to "pause" for a bit:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function contactDetails(x) {
  document.querySelector("selector7").value=x;
  document.querySelector("selector8").dispatchEvent(new Event('change',{
    bubbles: true
  }));
  await delay(5000);
  document.querySelector("selector9").click();
  document.querySelector("selector10").click();
  document.querySelector('selector11').click();
  await delay(1000);
  document.querySelector('selector12').click();
  await delay(1000);
  document.querySelector('selector13').click();
  await delay(500);
  document.querySelector('selector14').click();
}
```

(note that this requires making `contactDetails` an `async` function)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have async and await in your javascript repertoire:

```
function contactDetails(x) {
    document.querySelector("selector7").value=x;
    document.querySelector("selector8").dispatchEvent(new Event('change',{
        bubbles: true
    }));
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("selector9").click();
        document.querySelector("selector10").click();
        document.querySelector('selector11').click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('selector12').click();
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.querySelector("selector13").click();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.querySelector("selector14").click();
                }, 500);
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 5000);
};
```